# How to place 3D model using ARKit iOS 11 with some custom background view without using camera?

Tags: ios11, xcode9-beta, arkit

I am working on an Augmented Reality iOS app for which i am using ARKIT of iOS 11 beta. I am using ARSCNView(SceneKit) to render my .scn object. I have followed the sample given by apple in order to create an ARSession(https://developer.apple.com/sample-code/wwdc/2017/PlacingObjects.zip). Is it possible to place the 3D model with custom background instead of camera?

Like user can select the background color or can provide custom 2D photos as background?

Comment: You need to include some more information. What are you doing? Are you using SceneKit, what do you mean with "camera"?

Comment: @orangenkopf Sorry for the vague question. I have edited my question. I am using "SceneKit" and the sample "PlacingObjects" provided by apple.

Comment: So you don't want to have the camera stream as a scene background but something different? But than you don't have AR anymore? You can change the background of the `scene` to an image or a color: `scene.background.contents = UIColor.red`. I don't know if that works for ARKit too though.

Comment: @orangenkopf This is what exactly i needed!! I want to give user an option to place the object either using camera(AR) or with custom background. Thats why i need it. Thank you!!

Comment: Have you tried it and it works? Or does `ARKit` overrides the scene's background in some way?

Comment: I tried and it works. All functionalities of ARKit remains the same except the camera background being replaced with custom view.

Comment: How did you change camera contents back?

Comment: @ ooOlly Do not know if it is the correct approach but i stored the camera contents and when i switch back to original view, i set the camera source to the stored content again to bring back the camera view.

Comment: Thanks for your mind, saving my time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your view has a `scene` property where you can set the `background` to a color or an image:

```
 view.scene.background.contents = UIColor.red

 let myImage: UIImage = ... 
 view.scene.background.contents = myImage
```

Comment: Do you have any idea on how to revert this back to camera view? I just want to remove the background image and bring the camera back.

Comment: Try setting the contents to `nil`

Comment: No luck :( It just changes the background to white. Camera is not visible anymore.

Comment: @yaali, did you ever figure out a technique to get the camera back into view? Running into the same issue

Comment: I stored the camera contents and when i switch back to original view, i set the camera source to the stored content again to bring back the camera view.

Answer (score 0):

I use shake motion callback of `UIKit` to change background contents. As @yaali said, `CameraContents` is used to store camera contents. Notice that we can't get `background.contents` if the camera has not launched, for example on `viewWillAppear`. I guess `ARKit` set the `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` to `ARSCNView.scene.background.cocntents`.

```
    override func motionBegan(_ motion: UIEventSubtype, with event: UIEvent?) {
        if CameraContents == nil {
            CameraContents = sceneView.scene.background.contents;
            return
        }
        if cameraBackGround == true {
            sceneView.scene.background.contents = "Background_sky.png"
        }else{
            sceneView.scene.background.contents = CameraContents
        }
        cameraBackGround = !cameraBackGround

    }
```