# Reliable access and modify captured camera frames under SceneKit

Tags: objective-c, scenekit, arkit, cvpixelbuffer, arscnview

I try to add a B&W filter to the camera images of an ARSCNView, then render colored AR objects over it.

[image]

I'am almost there with the following code added to the beginning of `- (void)renderer:(id<SCNSceneRenderer>)aRenderer updateAtTime:(NSTimeInterval)time`

```
CVPixelBufferRef bg=self.sceneView.session.currentFrame.capturedImage;

if(bg){
    char* k1 = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddressOfPlane(bg, 1);
    if(k1){
        size_t x1 = CVPixelBufferGetWidthOfPlane(bg, 1);
        size_t y1 = CVPixelBufferGetHeightOfPlane(bg, 1);
        memset(k1, 128, x1*y1*2);
    }
}
```

This works really fast on mobile, but here's the thing: sometimes a colored frame is displayed. 
I've checked and my filtering code is executed but I assume it's too late, SceneKit's pipeline already processed camera input.

Calling the code earlier would help, but `updateAtTime` is the earliest point one can add custom frame by frame code.

Getting notifications on frame captures might help, but looks like the whole [AVCapturesession is unaccessible.](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/81971)

The Metal ARKit example shows how to convert the camera image to RGB and that is the place where I would do filtering, but that shader is hidden when using SceneKit.

I've tried [this possible answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45616125/2050892) but it's way too slow.

So how can I overcome the frame misses and convert the camera feed reliably to BW?

Comment: Just a ideas I have not tested myself: Could you use a [shaderModifier](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnshadable#1654834) to convert the background image to black and white by adding a fragment shader?

Comment: @orangenkopf definitely a way to go if the CVPixelBuffer method can not be fixed. What would you attach the shaderModifier to?

Comment: According the the [`ARSCNView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arscnview) docs the frame gets set as the scenes [`background`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnscene/1523665-background) which is a material property where you can attach a shader modifier. According to the comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45321275/how-to-place-3d-model-using-arkit-ios-11-with-some-custom-background-view-withou/45324663#45324663) it might not be that easy though

Comment: @orangenkopf wish that was doable, in fact material properties - like `background` - does not have shader modifiers, only materials and geometries do

Comment: I implemented this in swift and it works well. How can I darken the image?

Comment: @mehulmpt my assumption is that brightness data is on plane 0, just copy the code, switch plane indexes from 1 to 0, and start experimenting with lowering the values in that plane. A simple memset will not do, you'll need to do calculations when altering data so using the Accelerate framework might be handy.

Comment: @diviaki I've been studying YCbCr model since yesterday, and yeah I experimented with plane 0 as well. I was able to get individual pixel access using `var pixels = pixelBufferAddressOfPlane.assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt8.self)` on plane 0 and then `pixels` is an array containing that info. However, I'm clueless about how to manipulate this data correctly. If I set it to a single number (say 0 or 255), it seems like I'm getting only chroma data back with a funny image. However, if I try to reduce their value by a factor of 2 (by dividing each pixel value by 2), it either crashes or is very slow

Comment: .. and the divide by 2 effect doesn't work either (i see regular live feed only, it's just very jittery). how do I go about that? would really appreciate any help

Comment: @mehulmpt Grayscaling is easy as it simply clears color channels. If you want to darken the grayscale image, that should be simple as well by dividing Y values with Accelerate. However darkening the color image requires modifying all channels applying non-trivial calculations. Accelerate could help, but I would consider the alternate way that's easier to understand by using a shader to manipulate the RGB data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the key for this problem:

> [session:didUpdateFrame:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arsessiondelegate/2865611-session?language=objc)
>
> Provides a newly captured camera image and accompanying AR information to the delegate.

So just moved `CVPixelBufferRef` manipulation, the image filtering code from

```
- (void)renderer:(id<SCNSceneRenderer>)aRenderer updateAtTime:(NSTimeInterval)time
```

to

```
- (void)session:(ARSession *)session didUpdateFrame:(ARFrame *)frame
```

Made sure to set `self.sceneView.session.delegate = self` to have this delegate called.