# How to add black and white filter on arkit (swift4)

Tags: ios, filter, swift4, scenekit, arkit

All I want to do is take the basic arkit view and turn it into a black and white view. Right now the basic view is just normal and I have no idea on how add the filter. Ideally when taking a screenshot the black and white filter is added onto the screenshot.

```
import UIKit
import SceneKit
import ARKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, ARSCNViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var sceneView: ARSCNView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        sceneView.delegate = self
        sceneView.showsStatistics = true
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
        sceneView.session.run(configuration)
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        sceneView.session.pause()
    }

    @IBAction func changeTextColour(){
        let snapShot = self.augmentedRealityView.snapshot()
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(snapShot, self, #selector(image(_:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:)), nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you mean to post the same class twice?

Comment: @user1118321 no I just want the regular image to be turned to black and white.

Comment: Can you add your snapshot code?

Comment: @ArunB Ok I added the code at the very bottom.

Comment: Updated my answer to include live rendering in Black & White.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is possible, CoreImage Filters have a couple of ways to make monochrome and grayscale results. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/CIFunHouse/Introduction/Intro.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Filter ARSCNView Snapshot:** If you want to create a black and white screenShot of your `ARSCNView` you can do something like this which returns a `UIImage` in GrayScale and whereby `augmentedRealityView` refers to an `ARSCNView`:

```
/// Converts A UIImage To A High Contrast GrayScaleImage
///
/// - Returns: UIImage
func highContrastBlackAndWhiteFilter() -> UIImage?
{
    //1. Convert It To A CIIamge
    guard let convertedImage = CIImage(image: self) else { return nil }

    //2. Set The Filter Parameters
    let filterParameters = [kCIInputBrightnessKey: 0.0,
                            kCIInputContrastKey:   1.1,
                            kCIInputSaturationKey: 0.0]

    //3. Apply The Basic Filter To The Image
    let imageToFilter = convertedImage.applyingFilter("CIColorControls", parameters: filterParameters)

    //4. Set The Exposure
    let exposure =  [kCIInputEVKey: NSNumber(value: 0.7)]

    //5. Process The Image With The Exposure Setting
    let processedImage = imageToFilter.applyingFilter("CIExposureAdjust", parameters: exposure)

    //6. Create A CG GrayScale Image
    guard let grayScaleImage = CIContext().createCGImage(processedImage, from: processedImage.extent) else { return nil }

    return UIImage(cgImage: grayScaleImage, scale: self.scale, orientation: self.imageOrientation)
}
```

An example of using this therefore could be like so:

```
 override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    //1. Create A UIImageView Dynamically
    let imageViewResult = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.bounds.width, height: self.view.bounds.height))
    self.view.addSubview(imageViewResult)

    //2. Create The Snapshot & Get The Black & White Image
    guard let snapShotImage = self.augmentedRealityView.snapshot().highContrastBlackAndWhiteFilter() else { return }
    imageViewResult.image = snapShotImage

    //3. Remove The ImageView After A Delay Of 5 Seconds
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5) {
        imageViewResult.removeFromSuperview()
    }

}
```

Which will yield a result something like this:

[image]

In order to make your code reusable you could also create an `extension` of `UIImage:

```
//------------------------
//MARK: UIImage Extensions
//------------------------

extension UIImage
{

    /// Converts A UIImage To A High Contrast GrayScaleImage
    ///
    /// - Returns: UIImage
    func highContrastBlackAndWhiteFilter() -> UIImage?
    {
        //1. Convert It To A CIIamge
        guard let convertedImage = CIImage(image: self) else { return nil }

        //2. Set The Filter Parameters
        let filterParameters = [kCIInputBrightnessKey: 0.0,
                                kCIInputContrastKey:   1.1,
                                kCIInputSaturationKey: 0.0]

        //3. Apply The Basic Filter To The Image
        let imageToFilter = convertedImage.applyingFilter("CIColorControls", parameters: filterParameters)

        //4. Set The Exposure
        let exposure =  [kCIInputEVKey: NSNumber(value: 0.7)]

        //5. Process The Image With The Exposure Setting
        let processedImage = imageToFilter.applyingFilter("CIExposureAdjust", parameters: exposure)

        //6. Create A CG GrayScale Image
        guard let grayScaleImage = CIContext().createCGImage(processedImage, from: processedImage.extent) else { return nil }

        return UIImage(cgImage: grayScaleImage, scale: self.scale, orientation: self.imageOrientation)
    }

}
```

Which you can then use easily like so:

```
guard let snapShotImage = self.augmentedRealityView.snapshot().highContrastBlackAndWhiteFilter() else { return }
```

Remembering that you should place your extension above your `class declaration` e.g:

```
extension UIImage{

}

class ViewController: UIViewController, ARSCNViewDelegate {

}
```

So based on the code provided in your question you would have something like this:

```
/// Creates A Black & White ScreenShot & Saves It To The Photo Album
@IBAction func changeTextColour(){

    //1. Create A Snapshot
    guard let snapShotImage = self.augmentedRealityView.snapshot().highContrastBlackAndWhiteFilter() else { return }

    //2. Save It The Photos Album
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(snapShotImage, self, #selector(image(_:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:)), nil)

}

///Calback To Check Whether The Image Has Been Saved
@objc func image(_ image: UIImage, didFinishSavingWithError error: Error?, contextInfo: UnsafeRawPointer) {

    if let error = error {
        print("Error Saving ARKit Scene \(error)")
    } else {
        print("ARKit Scene Successfully Saved")
    }
}
```

**Live Rendering In Black & White:**
Using this brilliant answer here by [diviaki](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45919745/reliable-access-and-modify-captured-camera-frames-under-scenekit) I was also able to get the entire camera feed to render in Black and White using the following methods:

1st. Register for the `ARSessionDelegate` like so:

```
 augmentedRealitySession.delegate = self
```

2nd. Then in the following delegate callback add the following:

```
 //-----------------------
 //MARK: ARSessionDelegate
 //-----------------------

 extension ViewController: ARSessionDelegate{

 func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate frame: ARFrame) {

        /*
        Full Credit To https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45919745/reliable-access-and-modify-captured-camera-frames-under-scenekit
        */

        //1. Convert The Current Frame To Black & White
        guard let currentBackgroundFrameImage = augmentedRealityView.session.currentFrame?.capturedImage,
              let pixelBufferAddressOfPlane = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddressOfPlane(currentBackgroundFrameImage, 1) else { return }

        let x: size_t = CVPixelBufferGetWidthOfPlane(currentBackgroundFrameImage, 1)
        let y: size_t = CVPixelBufferGetHeightOfPlane(currentBackgroundFrameImage, 1)
        memset(pixelBufferAddressOfPlane, 128, Int(x * y) * 2)

      }

 }
```

Which successfully renders the camera feed Black & White:

[image]

**Filtering Elements Of An SCNScene In Black & White:**

As @Confused rightly said, If you decided that you wanted the `cameraFeed` to be in colour, but the contents of your `AR Experience` to be in Black & White you can apply a filter directly to an `SCNNode` using it's `filters` property which is simply:

> An array of Core Image filters to be applied to the rendered contents
>   of the node.

Let's say for example that we dynamically create 3 `SCNNodes` with a `Sphere Geometry` we can apply a `CoreImageFilter` to these directly like so:

```
/// Creates 3 Objects And Adds Them To The Scene (Rendering Them In GrayScale)
func createObjects(){

    //1. Create An Array Of UIColors To Set As The Geometry Colours
    let colours = [UIColor.red, UIColor.green, UIColor.yellow]

    //2. Create An Array Of The X Positions Of The Nodes
    let xPositions: [CGFloat] = [-0.3, 0, 0.3]

    //3. Create The Nodes & Add Them To The Scene
    for i in 0 ..< 3{

        let sphereNode = SCNNode()
        let sphereGeometry = SCNSphere(radius: 0.1)
        sphereGeometry.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = colours[i]
        sphereNode.geometry = sphereGeometry
        sphereNode.position = SCNVector3( xPositions[i], 0, -1.5)
        augmentedRealityView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(sphereNode)

        //a. Create A Black & White Filter
        guard let blackAndWhiteFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIColorControls", withInputParameters: [kCIInputSaturationKey:0.0]) else { return }
        blackAndWhiteFilter.name = "bw"
        sphereNode.filters = [blackAndWhiteFilter]
        sphereNode.setValue(CIFilter(), forKeyPath: "bw")
    }

}
```

Which will yield a result something like the following:

[image]

For a full list of these filters you can refer to the following: [CoreImage Filter Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html)

**Example Project:** Here is a complete [Example Project](https://github.com/BlackMirrorz/ARKitCameraFeedFilter) which you can download and explore for yourself.

Hope it helps...

Comment: I am having trouble saving the image. From you example project the image is not saving even though all of the code looks right.

Comment: I have now updated the code, and the example project. Please also mark my answer as correct :)

Comment: Great coding. If i wanted to keep the original colors of the 3 objects when taking a photo. How would I do that? black and white background with 3 colored balls over it.

Comment: The live rendering technique doesn't work for me because `session(_:didUpdate:)` is only called every few seconds

Comment: @BlackMirrorz Hi, I want to integrate color filter in ARKit using CIFilter, I have already posted my question on site, please have a look, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58501761/live-camera-is-getting-stretched-while-rendering-using-cifilter-swift-4 

if you have any batter idea to integrate it please share with me, Thank you.

Comment: For the Live Rendering In Black & White example, for me only some frames are black and white, not all frames, resulting in a "flickering" effect.

Comment: @BlackMirrorz Hi, I am still trying to obtain 2D image coordinates for 3D face tracking vertices. I obtained some 2D points using project point, however, but they do not seem to match with the MATLAB pixel coordinates. Could you please take a look and give me a hand if you have time and I could not find much info on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67305259/projectpoint-for-getting-2d-image-coordinates-in-arkit

Answer (score 13):

If you want to apply the filter in real-time the best way to achieve that is to use [`SCNTechnique`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scntechnique). Techniques are used for postprocessing and allow us to render an `SCNView` content in several passes – exactly what we need (first render a scene, then apply an effect to it).

Here's the [example project](https://github.com/2RKowski/ARSCNViewImageFiltersExample).

---

### Plist setup

First, we need to describe a technique in a `.plist` file.

Here's a screenshot of a `plist` that I've come up with (for better visualization):

[image: plist describing an SCNTechnique]

And here's it's source:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>sequence</key>
    <array>
        <string>apply_filter</string>
    </array>
    <key>passes</key>
    <dict>
        <key>apply_filter</key>
        <dict>
            <key>metalVertexShader</key>
            <string>scene_filter_vertex</string>
            <key>metalFragmentShader</key>
            <string>scene_filter_fragment</string>
            <key>draw</key>
            <string>DRAW_QUAD</string>
            <key>inputs</key>
            <dict>
                <key>scene</key>
                <string>COLOR</string>
            </dict>
            <key>outputs</key>
            <dict>
                <key>color</key>
                <string>COLOR</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

The topic of `SCNTechnique`s is quire broad and I will only quickly cover the things we need for the case at hand. To get a real understanding of what they are capable of I recommend reading [Apple's comprehensive documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scntechnique) on techniques.

**Technique description**

`passes` is a dictionary containing description of passes that you want an `SCNTechnique` to perform.

`sequence` is an array that specifies an order in which these passes are going to be performed using their keys.

You do not specify the main render pass here (meaning whatever is rendered without applying `SCNTechnique`s) – it is implied and it's resulting color can be accessed using `COLOR` constant (more on it in a bit).

So the only "extra" pass (besides the main one) that we are going to do will be `apply_filter` that converts colors into black and white (it can be named whatever you want, just make sure it has the same key in `passes` and `sequence`).

Now to the description of the `apply_filter` pass itself.

**Render pass description**

`metalVertexShader` and `metalFragmentShader` – names of `Metal` shader functions that are going to be used for drawing.

`draw` defines what the pass is going to render. `DRAW_QUAD` stands for:

> Render only a rectangle covering the entire bounds of the view. Use
>   this option for drawing passes that process image buffers output by
>   earlier passes.

which means, roughly speaking, that we are going to be rendering a plain "image" with out render pass.

`inputs` specifies input resources that we will be able to use in shaders. As I previously said, `COLOR` refers to a color data provided by a main render pass.

`outputs` specifies outputs. It can be `color`, `depth` or `stencil`, but we only need a `color` output. `COLOR` value means that we, simply put, are going to be rendering "directly" to the screen (as opposed to rendering into intermediate targets, for example).

---

### Metal shader

Create a `.metal` file with following contents:

```
#include <metal_stdlib>
using namespace metal;
#include <SceneKit/scn_metal>

struct VertexInput {
    float4 position [[ attribute(SCNVertexSemanticPosition) ]];
    float2 texcoord [[ attribute(SCNVertexSemanticTexcoord0) ]];
};

struct VertexOut {
    float4 position [[position]];
    float2 texcoord;
};

// metalVertexShader
vertex VertexOut scene_filter_vertex(VertexInput in [[stage_in]])
{
    VertexOut out;
    out.position = in.position;
    out.texcoord = float2((in.position.x + 1.0) * 0.5 , (in.position.y + 1.0) * -0.5);
    return out;
}

// metalFragmentShader
fragment half4 scene_filter_fragment(VertexOut vert [[stage_in]],
                                    texture2d<half, access::sample> scene [[texture(0)]])
{
    constexpr sampler samp = sampler(coord::normalized, address::repeat, filter::nearest);
    constexpr half3 weights = half3(0.2126, 0.7152, 0.0722);

    half4 color = scene.sample(samp, vert.texcoord);
    color.rgb = half3(dot(color.rgb, weights));

    return color;
}
```

Notice, that the function names for fragment and vertex shaders should be the same names that are specified in the `plist` file in the pass descriptor.

To get a better understanding of what `VertexInput` and `VertexOut` structures mean, refer to the [`SCNProgram` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnprogram).

The given vertex function can be used pretty much in any `DRAW_QUAD` render pass. It basically gives us normalized coordinates of the screen space (that are accessed with `vert.texcoord` in the fragment shader).

The fragment function is where all the "magic" happens. There, you can manipulate the texture that you've got from the main pass. Using this setup you can potentially implement a ton of filters/effects and more.

In our case, I used a basic desaturation (zero saturation) formula to get the black and white colors.

---

### Swift setup

Now, we can finally use all of this in the `ARKit`/`SceneKit`.

```
let plistName = "SceneFilterTechnique" // the name of the plist you've created

guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: plistName, withExtension: "plist") else {
    fatalError("\(plistName).plist does not exist in the main bundle")
}

guard let dictionary = NSDictionary(contentsOf: url) as? [String: Any] else {
    fatalError("Failed to parse \(plistName).plist as a dictionary")
}

guard let technique = SCNTechnique(dictionary: dictionary) else {
    fatalError("Failed to initialize a technique using \(plistName).plist")
}
```

and just set it as `technique` of the `ARSCNView`.

```
sceneView.technique = technique
```

That's it. Now the whole scene is going to be rendered in grayscale **including** when taking snapshots.

[image]

Comment: An interesting and well thought out answer :)

Comment: Hope you don't mind me borrowing your spheres idea :S

Comment: Very well explained. I am trying to have skin smoothing with use of meta. can you provide me any reference or any hint to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

The `snapshot` object should be an `UIImage`. Apply filters on this `UIImage` object by importing `CoreImage` framework and then apply Core Image filters on it. You should be adjusting the exposure and control values on the image. For more implementation details check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10030631/what-is-the-best-core-image-filter-to-produce-black-and-white-effects) . From iOS6, you can also use `CIColorMonochrome`filter to achieve the same effect.

Here is the apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIBoxBlur) for all the available filters. Click on each of the filters, to know the visual effects on the image upon application of the filter.

Here is the swift 4 code.

```
 func imageBlackAndWhite() -> UIImage?
    {
        if let beginImage = CoreImage.CIImage(image: self)
        {
            let paramsColor: [String : Double] = [kCIInputBrightnessKey: 0.0,
                                                  kCIInputContrastKey:   1.1,
                                                  kCIInputSaturationKey: 0.0]
            let blackAndWhite = beginImage.applyingFilter("CIColorControls", parameters: paramsColor)

            let paramsExposure: [String : AnyObject] = [kCIInputEVKey: NSNumber(value: 0.7)]
            let output = blackAndWhite.applyingFilter("CIExposureAdjust", parameters: paramsExposure)

            guard let processedCGImage = CIContext().createCGImage(output, from: output.extent) else {
                return nil
            }

            return UIImage(cgImage: processedCGImage, scale: self.scale, orientation: self.imageOrientation)
        }
        return nil
    }
```

Comment: This is from swift 3 and early do you know anything with swift 4.

Comment: How to I add this function to the snapShot.

Comment: Make this as an extension to UIImage, you will be able to do something like snapshot.imageBlackAndWhite()

Answer (score 0):

This might be the easiest and fastest way to do this:

Apply a CoreImage Filter to the Scene:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnnode/1407949-filters

This filter gives a very good impression of a black and white photograph, with good transitions through grays: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIPhotoEffectMono

You could also use this one, and get results easy to shift in hue, too:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIColorMonochrome

And here, in Japanese, is the proof of filters and SceneKit ARKit working together: http://appleengine.hatenablog.com/entry/advent20171215

Comment: The node.filters is a very interesting concept :)